# How do I enable 'focus follows mouse' in Lubuntu (LXDE)?

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-environments, lxde, focus

I would like to enable "focus follows mouse" bahavior in LXDE. How can I do it?

I would prefer a command-line solution.

Comment: @DKBose I don't know how to answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you are using openbox as the default file manager. I mainly know a GUI application of openbox configuration manager.

Run `obconf`, click on the mouse tab and check the checkbox focus windows when the mouse pointer moves over them. Then click the close button for this to apply.

I do not know of a command line way.

Answer (score 1):

> "I would prefer a command-line solution."

There isn't a built in command for this in Openbox, afaik. You will need to find the Openbox config file (**lubuntu-rc.xml**) and edit the line containing `<followMouse>no</followMouse>` by changing it to yes. The setting is a child of the `<focus>` element.

You can, however, use `sed` to achieve it:

```
sed -i 's/<followMouse>no<\/followMouse>/<followMouse>yes<\/followMouse>/g' ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

Just note that the name of the [config file](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration) will be different if you are not using Lubuntu. For bare Openbox or LXDE distros, find **openbox-rc.xml**.

Answer (score 0):

This works on raspberry pi.  Filename will be different for different distributions, but the principle remains the same.  Replace "lxde-pi-rc.xml" with the name of your openbox config file.

```
cd ~/.config/openbox
mv lxde-pi-rc.xml lxde-pi-rc.xml.save
sed 's/<followMouse>no</<followMouse>yes</' <lxde-pi-rc.xml.save >lxde-pi-rc.xml
```